# Sorting a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a 2D list:

```
mylist = [[9,7, 2, 2], [1,8, 2, 2], [2,9, 2, 2]]
```

Using a sort function, the list is sorted like this:

```
[[1, 8, 2, 2], [2, 9, 2, 2], [9, 7, 2, 2]]
```

But I want to sort this list like this:

```
[[9, 7, 2, 2],[1, 8, 2, 2], [2, 9, 2, 2]]
```

in which instead of the first digit of the list, I want to sort it by the last digit,
like using a sort function - it sorted by the first digit of the list.
I want to sort it by the last digit like 7 is smaller than 8 and 9 so 7 comes first.

Comment: `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `sorted()`  with `lambda`
Try this

```
In [1]: a=[[9, 7, 2, 2],[1, 8, 2, 2], [2, 9, 2, 2]]
In [4]: sorted(a,key=lambda a:a[::-1])
Out[4]: [[9, 7, 2, 2], [1, 8, 2, 2], [2, 9, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: In your answer you fixed it to second digit, i want to sort it by looking from end if last digits are same then it should look at second last digit.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
sorted(a,key=lambda a:list(reversed(a)))
```

Output:

```
[[9, 7, 2, 2], [1, 8, 2, 2], [2, 9, 2, 2]]
```